# Density of states of Bogoliubov quasiparticles

Tags: condensed-matter, density-of-states

For a simple fermionic system the formula for calculating the density of states (DOS) is $N(E) = \sum_{n}\delta(E-E_{n})$ where $\{E_{n}\}$ is the set of eigenvalues obtained after diagonalizing the hamiltonian. Now to diagonaloize a hamiltonian with pair correlation terms ($\sum_{k}c_{k\uparrow}^{\dagger}c_{-k\downarrow}^{\dagger}$) Bogoliubov transformation ($c_{k\uparrow}=u_{k}\gamma_{k\uparrow}-v_{k}^{\ast}\gamma_{-k\downarrow}^{\dagger}; c_{-k\downarrow}^{\dagger}=v_k\gamma_{k\uparrow}+u_{k}^{\ast}\gamma_{-k\downarrow}^{\dagger}$) is used. Now after diagonalizing we get a set of eigenvalues in the form:$\{E_n,-E_n\}\forall n$. Now to find the density of states I found a formula like this: $N(E)=\sum_{k}|u_k|^2\delta(E-E_k)+|v_k|^2\delta(E+E_k)$ where $\{E_k\}$ is the set of positive eigenvalues only. I don't understand this particular formula for density of states of bogoliubov quaisparticles. If anyone can explain it that would be very helpful.

Comment: Doesn't $\delta(E+E_k)$ account for the negative ones?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. But I was curious about the coefficients of $\delta(E+E_k)$ and $\delta(E-E_k)$

Comment: See http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/316542/density-of-states-in-k-space-for-the-bcs-hamiltonian

Answer (score 0):

Some information is missing, but I think that maybe if you expand the terms ($\sum_{k}c_{k\uparrow}^{\dagger}c_{-k\downarrow}^{\dagger}$) with the Bogoliubov transformation, some ortogonal operators may cancell and so you can separate the hamiltionian in terms of each $\gamma$ operator and $|u_k|^2$ and $|v_k|^2$. After that maybe you can separate the whole system into positive and negative energy states.

Answer (score 0):

Write BCS ground state ([reference](https://portal.ifi.unicamp.br/images/files/graduacao/aulas-on-line/fen-emerg/lecture_notes_BCS.pdf)) $|\Psi_{BCS}\rangle$:

$$|\Psi_{BCS}\rangle=\prod\limits_{\bf k}(u_{\bf k}+v_{\bf k}c_{\bf k\uparrow}^\dagger c_{\bf -k\downarrow}^\dagger)|0\rangle$$

and calculate the number density expectation:

$$\langle \hat n_{\bf k}\rangle=\langle c^\dagger_{\bf k}c_{\bf k}\rangle$$